# Hash batch of transactions using EIP712

Tags: solidity, uniswap, signature, eip712

Using Uniswap's `Permit2` contract as a base, how do I hash a batch of transactions in Solidity using EIP712?

This is the way for hashing a single transactions and it works without issues:

```js
return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
   "\x19\x01",
   permit2.DOMAIN_SEPARATOR(),
   keccak256(abi.encode(
       PERMIT_TRANSFER_FROM_TYPEHASH,
       keccak256(abi.encode(
           TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_TYPEHASH,
           permit.permitted.token,
           permit.permitted.amount
       )),
       spender,
       permit.nonce,
       permit.deadline
    ))
));
```

...where `permit` is the following `PermitTransferFrom` struct:

```js
struct PermitTransferFrom {
   TokenPermissions permitted;
   uint256 nonce;
   uint256 deadline;
}
```

```js
struct TokenPermissions {
   IERC20 token;
   uint256 amount;
}
```

How would that function be with the following `PermitBatchTransferFrom` struct:

```js
struct PermitBatchTransferFrom {
    TokenPermissions[] permitted;
    uint256 nonce;
    uint256 deadline;
}
```

The following values, I presume, should be used in the function, in the same way that `PERMIT_TRANSFER_FROM_TYPEHASH` and `TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_TYPEHASH` are used in the single tx function.

```js
bytes32 public constant _PERMIT_BATCH_TRANSFER_FROM_TYPEHASH = keccak256(
        "PermitBatchTransferFrom(TokenPermissions[] permitted,address spender,uint256 nonce,uint256 deadline)TokenPermissions(address token,uint256 amount)"
    );

bytes32 public constant _PERMIT_TRANSFER_FROM_TYPEHASH = keccak256(
        "PermitTransferFrom(TokenPermissions permitted,address spender,uint256 nonce,uint256 deadline)TokenPermissions(address token,uint256 amount)"
    );
```

You can browser through the following Uniswap article for more context: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/permit2/reference/signature-transfer#batched-permittransferfrom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```js
function getPermitBatchTransferSignature(
        ISignatureTransfer.PermitBatchTransferFrom memory permit,
        uint256 privateKey,
        bytes32 domainSeparator
    ) internal returns (bytes memory sig) {
        bytes32[] memory tokenPermissions = new bytes32[](permit.permitted.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < permit.permitted.length; ++i) {
            tokenPermissions[i] = keccak256(abi.encode(_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_TYPEHASH, permit.permitted[i]));
        }
        bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "\x19\x01",
                domainSeparator,
                keccak256(
                    abi.encode(
                        _PERMIT_BATCH_TRANSFER_FROM_TYPEHASH,
                        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tokenPermissions)),
                        address(this),
                        permit.nonce,
                        permit.deadline
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = vm.sign(privateKey, msgHash);
        return bytes.concat(r, s, bytes1(v));
    }
```